# Chrome dev tools won't open. How do I troubleshoot that?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a chrome browser open.  I press `f12` and nothing happens.  I click the three dots at the top right, click More Tools, click Developer Tools, and nothing happens.  The Developer Tools options is not grayed out.  There is no icon in the task bar so this isn't a "hidden window" issue.  I've restarted Chrome.  I've rebooted and I've uninstalled/reinstalled Chrome.  I'm on Chrome version Version 89.0.4389.82 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Windows 10 Version 1909 (OS Build 18363.1440).  What steps can I take to resolve this.

UPDATE: Using chrome task manager, I do see that the dev tools process is being kicked off and running, it's just not visible in any way.

UPDATE 2: If I run in incognito mode, devtools works.  I have already disabled all extensions and cleared all site data (cookies and files).  Still nothing for devtools in non-incognito chrome.

[image: DevTools Running]

Comment: As a workaround you can start chrome with `--remote-debugging-port=1234` then open `http://localhost:1234/` and inspect from there.

Comment: I appreciate that, that also does not seem to work.

Comment: Something is completely broken deep inside. Maybe it's a windows bug.

Comment: it works in Incognito mode.  All my extensions are already disabled, but that seems to indicate something extension related.

Comment: I got into the same trouble and have no idea. Have you solved the problem?